# How to click a Link on a webpage using VBScript

Tags: html, internet-explorer, vbscript

Actually i have to click on a link and as a result it will be give two menu list in that i need to select any of those

here is my VBScript for launching IE and navigate to required web adress

```
Dim URL 
Dim IE 
Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
URL = "http://it-asg.uhc.com/sites/gcas/pcas/archive/PCR/IVM/modlist/Lists/ElementTracker/AllItems.aspx" 
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate URL
```

Can any any one help me out to click on that link and select any one of those menu 
source for the link

Actual source for the link :

```
<a id="zz13_ListActionsMenu" accesskey="C" href="#" onclick="javascript:return false;" style="cursor ointer;white-space:nowrap;" onfocus="MMU_EcbLinkOnFocusBlur(byid('zz8_RptControls'), this, true);" onkeydown="MMU_EcbLinkOnKeyDown(byid('zz8_RptControls'), MMU_GetMenuFromClientId('zz13_ListActionsMenu'), event);" oncontextmenu="this.click(); return false;" menutokenvalues="MENUCLIENTID=zz13_ListActionsMenu,TEMPLATECLIENTID=zz8_RptControls" serverclientid="zz13_ListActionsMenu">Actions<img src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" border="0" alt="Use SHIFT+ENTER to open the menu (new window)."></a>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

For this scenario you can use the method "getElementById". For example:

```
IE.Document.getElementById("zz13_ListActionsMenu").Click
```

So your code will look something like:

```
Dim URL 
Dim IE 
Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
URL = "http://it-asg.uhc.com/sites/gcas/pcas/archive/PCR/IVM/modlist/Lists/ElementTracker/AllItems.aspx" 
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate URL


 Do While IE.Busy
    WScript.Sleep 100
 Loop

IE.Document.getElementById("zz13_ListActionsMenu").Click
```

There are also other methods you can use to access and click elements on a page, I refer to the following for a list:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535862(v=vs.85).aspx