# Automate IE with vbscript - Can not click the buttons

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript, click, submit

Can someone give me a hint, how to click the buttons (the addButton)? 
Tryed something like
IE.Document.All.Item("addButton").Click 
(and more) but that does not work.

HTML Code:

```
<form action="./snfDestServlet" method="post" id="destForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="UTF-8">
<div id="destBox" class="indented"><select id="destinations" size="6" name="dests">
<option value="scanToNet.factory.9">MDS</option>
<option value="scanToNet.factory.11">Host1-SMB</option>
<option value="scanToNet.factory.10">Host2-SMB</option>
</select>
</div>
<div id="destinationButtons">
<input type="submit" name="addButton" value="Hinzufügen..."></input>
<br></br>
<input type="submit" name="editButton" value="Bearbeiten..."></input>
<br></br>
<input type="submit" name="deleteButton" value="Löschen"></input>
</div>
<br class="clear"></br>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to my answer in the following thread:

[How to click a Link on a webpage using VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18593499/how-to-click-a-link-on-a-webpage-using-vbscript/18597101#18597101)

For this scenario you can use the method "getElementById". For example:

```
IE.Document.getElementById("destinationButtons").Click
```

So your code will look something like:

```
Dim URL 
Dim IE 
Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
URL = "http://whateverURLyouWant.com" 
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate URL


 Do While IE.Busy
    WScript.Sleep 100
 Loop

IE.Document.getElementById("destinationButtons").Click
```

There are also other methods you can use to access and click elements on a page, I refer to the following for a list:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535862(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Sorry my mistake.

IE.Document.All.Item("addButton").Click works fine, but i was in the wrong frame ...

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim IE

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

IE.Visible = 1 
IE.FullScreen = 0
IE.navigate "www.anything.com"

Do While (IE.Busy)
    WScript.Sleep (10)
Loop

IE.Document.getElementById("Button_ID").click
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please remember to make sure you [format your code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).